# How to execute CompletableFuture function and get the result either which of them is done first?

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, completable-future

i already have create 3 function that execute query to database, then i want to get each result and add into one List of object but the result is always empty, how can i do this properly? here is what i do :

i create 3 CompletableFuture function :

```
private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findPureUnAssignedSO() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> iSalesOrderMapper.entityToSOOnlyDto(iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findUnAssignedSalesOrder()));
}

private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSOHaveLeftOverButDone();
        return buildTransSalesOrdersResponseNew(transSalesOrders);
    });
}

private CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        List<TransSalesOrder> transSalesOrders = iTransSalesOrderQdslRepository.findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder();

        return buildTransSalesOrdersBpsjOnlyResponseNew(transSalesOrders); 
    });
}
```

and then here is how i try to execute that 3 function :

ATTEMPT 1, using get() :

```
public List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findUnAssignedSO() {
    CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        transSalesOrdersResponseNew = findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly().get();
        transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(findPureUnAssignedSO().get());
        transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder().get());
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
}
```

the result still empty

ATTEMPT 2 :

```
public List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> findUnAssignedSO() {
    List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = new ArrayList<>();

    CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> soHaveItemLeftOverOnly = findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly();
    CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> pureUnAssignedSO = findPureUnAssignedSO();
    CompletableFuture<List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto>> salesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder = findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder();

    CompletableFuture.allOf(soHaveItemLeftOverOnly, pureUnAssignedSO, salesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder)
            .thenRun(() -> {
                transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(soHaveItemLeftOverOnly.join());
                transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(pureUnAssignedSO.join());
                transSalesOrdersResponseNew.addAll(salesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder.join());
                });

    }

    return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
}
```

the result is always empty if i do this, even i use .get() to block the result, how do i do completablefuture properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your attempts aren't working because you call an a completion stage without waiting for the result (I'm not sure about attempt number 1 though).

I don't know the signature of all the methods, but if somewhere you are returning a `CompletionStage` in the `supplyAsync` and you don't use `thenCompose` instead, the function will return ignoring the result of the CompletionStage

In Attempt number 2, it's easier to see where it's wrong. It's this part:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(...).thenRun(() -> ...);
```

It doesn't matter what you do in the `thenRun` part. You don't wait anywhere for the result, so it will get to the `return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;` immediately, even if the function you have defined in the `thenRun` part hasn't finished yet.

Assuming that the methods `findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly`, `findPureUnAssignedSO` and `findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder` are correct (we cannot  know that from the details you gave use), you could rewrite the code this way:

```
final List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = ... ;

findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly()
   .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
   .thenCompose( v -> findPureUnAssignedSO() )
   .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
   .thenCompose( v -> findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder() )
   .thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
   .join();

return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
```

Note that I'm using `.thenCompose`, this will use the result of the function as the next `CompletionStage` in the sequence. This way you won't lose result in the process.

You could also run the find methods in parallel (if the order doesn't matter) with `CompletableFuture.allOf` but in that case you need to make sure to use an implementation of List that's thread safe.
It would look like this:

```
final List<TransSalesOrderOnlyResponseDto> transSalesOrdersResponseNew = ... // Thread-safe list implementation;

CompletableFuture.allOf(
    findSOHaveItemLeftOverOnly().thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll ),
    findPureUnAssignedSO().thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll ),
    findSalesOrderWithBpsjInDeliveryOrder().thenAccept( transSalesOrdersResponseNew::addAll )
).join();

return transSalesOrdersResponseNew;
```

Comment: I've just realized you could use method reference

Comment: oh think that way should work, cause i just got error org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.bit.microservices.b2b.warehouse.entity.TransSalesOrder.transDeliveryOrder, could not initialize proxy - no Session, i should google it first

Comment: That error is unrelated to the question, though. Anyway, I've added some details to my answer trying to explain why the other approaches you have used didn't work.

Comment: Please, remember to accept the answer if it was correct for the question you have asked

Comment: sure, well explained and it work, thank u Davide